# How does SQL Telemetry get installed on a server?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

Can someone help me please?

How is `SQL Telemetry` different from `Microsoft Error Reporting` that you get during a SQL install?

I installed a successful `SQL 2016 FCI` instance, verified the installation, failed over and back all successfully. Then needed to restart the services the following day and had problems doing so, for no obvious reason. The problem was then fixed by a colleague removing the `SQL Telemetry` service.

How would this have been installed and what is it?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How would this have been installed and what is it?

The `CEIP` Service is the `Customer Experience Improvement Program` that sends telemetry data back to Microsoft.

When you install Microsoft SQL Server, the `CEIP` Service is installed too.
You can’t disable it during installation: it shows up in your services list whether you want it or not.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/10/what-is-the-sql-server-ceip-service/

If you're using Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition - you can disable the CEIP service

if you’re using Developer Edition or Express Edition, you can't disable CEIP service

> How is SQL Telemetry different from Microsoft Error Reporting that you get during a SQL install?

Error Reporting sends error information and details to Microsoft
Telemetry sends much more data related to usage of the SQL Server in question

Comment: Thank you @Aleksey Vitsko. Yes I saw that article from Brentozar but I don't understand how if it is installed by default, it didn't cause a problem one day and then when I needed to restart services the following day, it caused a problem?

Comment: @PTL_SQL how do you know that exactly  SQL Server CEIP service caused a problem with restarting services?  you've got to provide a proof

Comment: Once the service was removed by my colleague, the SQL cluster started. I don't understand it either, that's why I'm asking about it. Thanks all the same for your time and interest, much appreciated.

Comment: @PTL_SQL honestly I do not have a theory for this. Edited my answer. My Answer provides answers for your main questions. If you have seen brentozar article already, why would you ask these questions on DBA Stackexchange ?

Answer (score 0):

and thank you @AlekseyVitsko for your time, much appreciated.

I actually did this myself again and found the strange issue:

- I installed SQL2016 FCI cluster successfully
- Cluster was fully running as it should until...
- I rebooted one of the servers to verify the installation, and the cluster that had been running successfully would not come back up.
- I did everything I could in Windows Failover Cluster Manager, still the cluster wouldn't start.
- Until ..... I removed the CEIP Resource in Cluster Manager and everything started working perfectly!!
- Note, not the service, the CEIP service was still there even though not running. I didn't do anything with the service.
- Strange!! This was my first experience with installing FCI and I did as much reading/prep as I could get before that first installation. What my colleague did was not mentioned in any reading I did. Now I tried it again myself and found it is true.

Thanks again for your time, much appreciated.